# SonarQube GitHub Pull Request Decorating not working

Tags: github, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I am trying to get SonarQube to decorate pull requests in a private github.com repository. The analysis is triggered by an azure pipeline using the official [SonarQube plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube). Analysis works fine and is being triggered for branches and PRs.

I then followed the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/pr-decoration/) to enable pull request decorating, and checked it twice since it isn't working.

The SonarQube logs will always show the following two lines

```
2020.02.12 08:41:05 WARN  [c.s.C.B.B.B] Failed to access GitHub, the repository or the Pull Request
2020.02.12 08:41:05 INFO  [o.s.c.t.p.a.p.PostProjectAnalysisTasksExecutor] Pull Request decoration | status=SUCCESS | time=966ms
```

I am not sure how it cannot get access to GitHub/the repository/the PR but still show a success message for pull request decoration. Is it the decoration feature that was configured falsely or can it be something else that is wrong?

I am using SonarQube Developer Edition - Version 8.1